# Import Android project error

Tags: android, import, directory, r.java-file

I download a Android open source code from web.

When I import it to library,it don't have a "gen folder",so I manually

create one then I use "refresh" and "Project clean ..."

The eclipse still don't auto generate the R.java file.

And why I can't "" import com.codeminders.ardrone.ARDrone;"

I already have the folder in my project.

How can I fix this?!

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/33585022/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-22%20at%208.41.05%20AM.png

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have an unresolved build pathing problem or there is an error in one of your xml files.

After looking at yoru image, the package that you are referencing does not match anything in what you have in your explorer. It must have a matching package reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a jar file or a project library that you used. Try adding them in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, and i fixed this. Remember that i shouldn't modify or create a R file. I think you got an error with Eclipse. Try download new Elipse and exactly Android SDK. Good luck